# How to convert this formula from excel to M language?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm try convert the formula bellow to Power BI M language

```
=IF(AC4>TIMEVALUE("20:00:00");"After the deadline";"In the term")
```

I tried formula bellow but doesn't work, it return this error message "The name 'IF' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.":

```
=IF(
TIMEVALUE([#"(Transf1-Coleta)"]) > TIMEVALUE("20:00:00"),
"After the deadline",
"In the term"
)
```

The column [#"(Transf1-Coleta)"] is the same value of column "AC" and "AD" is the value that want get

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want DAX? If it isn't recognizing IF, then I suspect you might be working in the Query Editor which uses the M language, not DAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using **Measure**, try this below code-

```
=IF(
    TIMEVALUE(min(table_name[column_name])) > TIMEVALUE("20:00:00"),
    "After the deadline",
    "In the term"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In M

```
= Table.AddColumn(#PreviousStep, "Custom", each if DateTime.Time([Transf1-Coleta])>Time.FromText("20:00:00") then "After the Deadline" else"In the term")
```